# mergering two for loops to map 1 value to other 1 to1 mapping

Tags: python

```
a =['1','2','3']
b =['A','B','C']

for i in a:
   print(i)
output:
1
2
3

for i in b:
  print(i)

output:
A
B
C
```

I want to map 1 , A
2, B
3, C

so that i can store the value in DB in one for loop parallely

```
for i , n in a,b:
  print i,n
```

This is not allowed

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `zip()` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip).

```
a = ['1','2','3']
b = ['A','B','C']

for i, n in zip(a, b):
    print(i, n)
```

Comment: Great work, you got there before me. I have deleted my answer.